# CSS position and scale object by resolution

Tags: javascript, html, css, position, scale

[I'm trying to achieve this in css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiHGr.png)

How would I go about it?
I couldn't make it fill the empty space on the sides, can I do it in css only (and so it works with browser zooming as well)

This is my code (simplified), since nothing was working for me I provide a raw code

```css
<html>
<head>
    <style>        
        #parent {
            width: 1000px;
            height: 1000px;
            background-color: #0ff;
        }
        
        .child {
            width: 400px;
            height: 200px;
            margin: 20px;
            background-color: #f00;
            float: left;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="parent">
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide the code you are trying. Just a reminder, before you post a question, please check the existing questions. I believe there are questions related [Responsive design](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/responsive-design)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `flexbox`

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/o7yb0vts/)

```css
#parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: #0ff;
}
.child {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

style the parent container ( if you don't have one then create it ) as follows

```
.parent {
display:flex;
flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.child {
flex: 1;
width: 45%;  /* whatever you want on the bigger screen */

@media ( min-width : 500px ) {

    .child {
       width:100% ;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried doing that, my problem was that it doesn't affect when the user uses the browser zoom

Comment: You should create a working example, because this https://jsfiddle.net/nswcrhaf/ does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox is really good at this kind of things :

[Demo on Codepen](http://codepen.io/jeremythille/pen/YqoOmw?editors=1100) (or run it below)

```css
div.out {
  border: #f00 solid 1px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}
div.out div.flex {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
      -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
          flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: #00f dashed 1px;
  width: 100%;
}
div.out div.flex div.in {
  min-width: 300px;
  border: #008000 solid 5px;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
      -ms-flex-positive: 1;
          flex-grow: 1;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}
div.out div.flex div.in h2 {
  font-size: 2rem;
}


/* Below : just for the animation */

div.out {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
          animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-name: changewidth;
          animation-name: changewidth;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
          animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
          animation-direction: alternate;
}
@-webkit-keyframes changewidth {
  from {
    width: 300px;
  }
  to {
    width: 800px;
  }
}
@keyframes changewidth {
  from {
    width: 300px;
  }
  to {
    width: 800px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="out">
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="in">
      <h2>Content1</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="in">
      <h2>Content2</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```